# How to write success message of form in bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

**SOLVED**

Ok, I solved the problem with AJAX but I had to delete my WordPress because it didn't work with it so later I will upload back by individual directory. Luckily I don't need it for my index. The working code is by [CodexWorld](https://www.codexworld.com/bootstrap-modal-popup-form-submit-jquery-ajax-php/). I hope I help someone who is helpless.

---

I am searching for solution all day but I don't get relevant solution anywhere. Other similar questions here are old, maybe there are fresh solution.

So I am using Bootstrap the first time (files are on the themes of Wordpress). I started to build a contact form in Modal and if I hit submit the window closes, I get the e-mail, but the success-message only shows if I reopen it. I tried every solution I found on internet.

I am not familiar with javascript and jquery, I don't know how to use it.

In the footer I implemented:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In index there is the form with Modal:

```
 <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
    <form class="form-horizontal clearfix" id="contact-form" name="contact" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Küldj egy üzenetet</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Itt landol</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text" placeholder="hello@kanizsaipatricia.hu" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Név</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Minta János" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="valaki@email.hu" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Üzenet</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Ide írd az üzenetet" rows="4" name="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>

                        <?php echo $result; ?>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-cancel hvr-fade" data-dismiss="modal">Mégsem</button>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resultModal" value="Elküldöm" class="btn btn-info hvr-wobble-horizontal">
    </div>  
</pop:form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The php code behind the form:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'Üzenetküldő űrlap'; 
    $to = 'hello@kanizsaipatricia.hu'; 
    $subject = 'Új üzenet formon keresztül';

    $body = "Feladó: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Üzenet:\n $message";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Kérlek, add meg a neved!';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Nem érvényes e-mail cím!';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Nem írtál üzenetet.';
    }


// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success noshadow">Elküldve.</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger noshadow">Sajnálom, hiba lépett fel az üzenet küldése közben. Próbáld újra!</div>';
    }
}
}
```

I'm open minded for any solution in any language! Please help!

Comment: Is all of this code in the same file?

Comment: switch to using ajax to post the form, based on the response, hide/show msgs... how are you showing these  errors `<?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>`, or do you need to re-open the modal to see them?...

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't know how to switch to ajax. I already saw a lot of solutions with ajax but any of them worked at all. Could you write a solution how-to? I don't care if I have to open a new modal to show the result message or it shows in the same. I'm open minden for any solution of these...

Comment: @JeremyHamm Jeremy, there are 3 files because of the wordpress theme: header, index, footer, but the index includes the header and the footer as well this way: `<?php get_header()` and `<?php get_footer()`

Comment: and yes, @LawrenceCherone I have to reopen the modal to see those error messages too... I forgot to answer for this question.

Comment: if you dont want to use AJAX then your not open to the solution.. please add what you have tried regarding "I already saw a lot of solutions with ajax but any of them worked at all.". then we can help you find a solution...

Comment: @LawrenceCherone is correct this is usually done with AJAX.  The purpose of AJAX is to be asynchronous.  This complete an operation and display the output without requiring a page refresh.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't say I don't want to use ajax. I just said please write a how-to if you don't mind because I don't know ajax at all and anything I tried didn't work.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for the ajax idea, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem with ajax but I had to delete my WordPress because it didn't work with it so later I will upload back by individual directory. Luckily I don't need it for my index. [Thanks to CodexWorld](https://www.codexworld.com/bootstrap-modal-popup-form-submit-jquery-ajax-php/).

**Bootstrap & jQuery Library**

Bootstrap is used to create modal popup and design HTMl form, include the bootstrap and jQuery library first.

```
    <!-- Latest minified bootstrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest minified bootstrap js -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Bootstrap Modal Popup Form**

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalForm">
    Open Contact Form
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalForm" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Contact Form</h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="statusMsg"></p>
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputName">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputMessage">Message</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" onclick="submitContactForm()">SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code: Validate and Submit Form**

```
<script>
function submitContactForm(){
    var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var name = $('#inputName').val();
    var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
    var message = $('#inputMessage').val();
    if(name.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your name.');
        $('#inputName').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(email.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your email.');
        $('#inputEmail').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(email.trim() != '' && !reg.test(email)){
        alert('Please enter valid email.');
        $('#inputEmail').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(message.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your message.');
        $('#inputMessage').focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'submit_form.php',
            data:'contactFrmSubmit=1&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&message='+message,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
            },
            success:function(msg){
                if(msg == 'ok'){
                    $('#inputName').val('');
                    $('#inputEmail').val('');
                    $('#inputMessage').val('');
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Thanks for contacting us, we\'ll get back to you soon.</p>');
                }else{
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                }
                $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

**Send Contact Request Email (submit_form.php)**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['contactFrmSubmit']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) && !empty($_POST['message'])){

    // Submitted form data
    $name   = $_POST['name'];
    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $message= $_POST['message'];

    /*
     * Send email to admin
     */
    $to     = 'admin@example.com';
    $subject= 'Contact Request Submitted';

    $htmlContent = '
    <h4>Contact request has submitted at CodexWorld, details are given below.</h4>
    <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th><td>'.$name.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
            <th>Email:</th><td>'.$email.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Message:</th><td>'.$message.'</td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From: CodexWorld<sender@example.com>' . "\r\n";

    // Send email
    if(mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers)){
        $status = 'ok';
    }else{
        $status = 'err';
    }

    // Output status
    echo $status;die;
}
```